# Obtener valores numéricos de un string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de obtener los valor numericos dentro de un string en este caso del nombre de los `input`:

Código:

```
var element   = $(this).attr("name").substring(6,7).match(/\d+/);
var only      = $(this).attr("name").substring(7,10).match(/\d+/);
```

El problema es que no siempre están ubicados en la misma posición o estos se corren ya que la cantidad de dígitos cambia.

Ejemplo de los `names`:

```
name="i_txt_7_14"
    
name="i_txt_27_14"

name="i_txt_136_140"
```

Como observaran hay un completo desfase si uso el `substring(6,7)` y `substring(7,10)` falla; como puedo obtener los datos numéricos teniendo en cuenta que siempre se cumple el patrón de separación `i_txt_` y luego `_`.

¿Cómo puedo obtener los valores numéricos sin que falle, de forma dinámica?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<sub>(Te propongo una solución con `Javascript` puro, sin necesidad de utilizar `JQuery`).</sub>

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar la función `match` para obtener todos los valores que sean número.

Le podrías pasar una regex que indicara que quieres coger todos los números.

Ejemplo:

```js
var regex = /(\d+)/g;

var name="i_txt_7_14";
console.log(name.match(regex)); 

var name2="i_txt__________7_14";
console.log(name2.match(regex)); 

var name3="i_t10xt_7_14";
console.log(name3.match(regex));
```

La explicación de la regex:

- `\d` indica que quieres que coja números
- `/g` indica que quieres buscar de manera global en todo el string.

Comment: gracias por tu aporte lo tomare en cuenta para la solución.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Si ejecutas mi ejemplo te devuelve un array por cada string con los números que ha obtenido.

Answer (score 7):

Puedes realizar lo siguiente: crear una *función* que reciba por un *parámetro* la *cadena* a la cual le deseas extraer los números, convertir esta *cadena* en un *arreglo*, con un `Array.map()` devuelves los elementos que sean números y con un `Array.filter()` eliminas los elementos que hayan quedado como undefined y por último le realizas un `Array.join()` al resultado para obtener una cadena del número completo:

```js
var name_1 = "i_txt_7_14";
var name_2 = "i_txt_27_14";
var name_3 = "i_txt_136_140";

function getNumbersInString(string) {
  var tmp = string.split("");
  var map = tmp.map(function(current) {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(current))) {
      return current;
    }
  });

  var numbers = map.filter(function(value) {
    return value != undefined;
  });

  return numbers.join("");
}

console.log(getNumbersInString(name_1)); // Nos devolverá 714
console.log(getNumbersInString(name_2)); // Nos devolverá 2714
console.log(getNumbersInString(name_3)); // Nos devolverá 136140
```

Comment: gracias por tu comentario pero no quiero recojer un solo gran valor numérico, si ves trato de guardarlo variables distintas.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumAges(firstUserPhrase, SecondUserPhrase, ThirdUserPhrase) {

var regex = /(\d+)/g;
let resultado1= firstUserPhrase.match(regex);
let resultado2= SecondUserPhrase.match(regex) ;
let resultado3= ThirdUserPhrase.match(regex) ;

let cambio1= parseInt(resultado1);
let cambio2 = parseInt(resultado2);
let cambio3 = parseInt(resultado3);

return(cambio1+cambio2+cambio3)
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente _qué hace este código_. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: si debería de agregarle una mejor descripción ... la verdad no se que hace este código