# ¿Cómo convertir varios tipos de valores de texto a número?

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

Tengo que convertir 2 tipos de valores de texto a número, los valores son así:

**Tipo 1: 90'**

**Tipo 2: 90'+5'**

Son tiempos y minutos de fútbol, y como el valor no siempre es con el formato `xx'`, sino que a veces se les agrega el signo +, se me dificulta crear la función, sino con `indexOf` es fácil si solo es un número.

Seguro alguien ya debe tener un código creado que evalúe ambas posibilidades y por eso lo expongo acá a ver si me ayudan.

Gracias.

Comment: Creo que lo que necesitas lo puedes encontrar [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95661/obtener-valores-num%C3%A9ricos-de-un-string)<br>
Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui te dejo una funcion:

```js
var t1 = "90'"
var t2 = "90' + 5'";

function getMinutos(tiempo) {
  var t = 0;
  var secc = tiempo.split("+");
  if (secc.length > 1) {
    t = parseInt(secc[0]) + parseInt(secc[1]);
  } else {
    t = parseInt(secc[0]);
  }
  
  return t;
}

console.log(getMinutos(t1));
console.log(getMinutos(t2));
```

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas podrias remplazar las `'` por `""` asi tendrias los numeros separados por el signo `+`. Con lo anterior podrias obtener un arreglo utilizando la función `split("+")` con lo que obtendras una lista de numeros que puedes sumar.

Para sumar utilice la función `reduce()`. A continuación te muestro un ejemplo:

```js
    var x = "90'"
    var y = "90'+5'"
    function getMinutos(str){
     return str.replace(/\'/g,"").split("+").reduce(function(total, x){
        return parseInt(total) + parseInt(x);
     })
    }
    console.log(getMinutos(x));
    console.log(getMinutos(y));
```

Comment: solo pegar un fragmento de código como respuesta se considera de baja calidad; dale editar y explica como tu respuesta es la solución

Comment: ok. entiendo gracias por el comentario @shadow